# Label align in Mozilla

Tags: css

In Chrome, my label is aligned correctly, but not in Mozilla and IE. How can I fix this?

HTML :

```
<div >              
    <label >Domaine d'activité</label>                      
</div>
```

CSS :

```
label {
    vertical-align: top;
}
label:BEFORE {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #435a8b;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px 6px 0;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL8N4/)

Comment: can you put a image which shows exactly what you expect

Comment: open the fiddle link in chrome and you will see

Comment: ya but i haven't chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not really need to use `vertical-align: top;` on `label` just define it on `:before` element. Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL8N4/4/)**.

```
label {
    /*vertical-align: top;*/ /*Not required */
}
label:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #435a8b;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `vertical-align: middle;` into `label:before`

You can see the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfHrT/